# Unity 7.4 backport (Trusty)?

Tags: 14.04, unity, backport

Is there unofficial ppa or way to build (backport) Unity 7.4 (or newer) to Trusty (I'm looking for bottom launcher feature, without breaking fglrx)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official PPA.

In theory, you should just need to grab the source packages for Compiz and Unity from Ubuntu 16.04 and build them yourself using dpkg-buildpackage.  You could even upload to your own PPA to do the building for you.

The catch is the newer Unity may require a newer GTK+.  Try it and see.